# import Sakila Database to PhpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to import Sakila DB to PhpMyAdmin in Windows but I can't , I can import Schema to phpmyadmin in import section but i cant import sakila data to that , when I do that I'm getting the following error -

> No data was received to import. Either no file name was submitted, or
>   the file size exceeded the maximum size permitted by your PHP
>   configuration. See FAQ 1.16.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

go through this link.
[mysqli dump example](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/sakila/en/sakila-installation.html)

If your database file more than 2MB then you have use the Command prompt.

```
mysql -u username -p password

use databsname
source PATH-TO-SQL-FILE (E:/Folder/File.sql)
```